# select first occurance of minimum index from numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find out the index of the minimum value in each row and I am using below code.

```
#code
import numpy as np
C = np.array([[1,2,4],[2,2,5],[4,3,3]])
ind = np.where(C == C.min(axis=1).reshape(len(C),1))
ind

#output
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

but the problem it is returning all indices of minimum values in each row. but I want only the first occurrence of minimum values. like

```
(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Use `argmin` : `C.argmin(1)` and `np.arange(C.shape[0])` for the row indices.

Comment: Divakar Thanks, please add it in answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use comparison against the minimum value, we need to use `np.min` and keep the dimensions with `keepdims` set as `True` to give us a boolean array/mask. To select the first occurance, we can use `argmax` along each row of the mask and thus have our desired output.

Thus, the implementation to get the corresponding column indices would be -

```
(C==C.min(1, keepdims=True)).argmax(1)
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
In [114]: C   # Input array
Out[114]: 
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [2, 2, 5],
       [4, 3, 3]])

In [115]: C==C.min(1, keepdims=1) # boolean array of min values
Out[115]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [116]: (C==C.min(1, keepdims=True)).argmax(1) # argmax to get first occurances
Out[116]: array([0, 0, 1])
```

The first output of row indices would simply be a range array -

```
np.arange(C.shape[0])
```

---

To achieve the same column indices of first occurance of minimum values, a direct way would be to use `np.argmin` -

```
C.argmin(axis=1)
```